# Texts dont show on release build for an adobe air mobile app with localization support

Tags: air, adobe, flash-builder

I am building a mobile application with localization support. The app supports three languages and it is targeted for android and ios. Everything works fine for debug builds; i can test everything for all the languages. When i do a release build, all the text on the app disappear! Buttons show with no text. If i change some of them to no use resourcemanager, the changed ones show the text. Does anyone knows why would this happen? I am using Flashbuilder 4.6, Apache Flex 4.11 air 13 beta.

Thanks.

Comment: are you embedding your fonts in the App?

Comment: No, I am not embedding fonts.

Comment: 1. Which are the fonts you are using ? 2. If you are not embedding the fonts, then are the fonts installed on your device?

Comment: I am not using any special font in the app, just stylings for the size, weight and colors, here and there.

Comment: its trick, not to solve the answer

1.build a app with just a single label, check in both(dev, release)

Comment: 2. Embed a font and use in this label with style, then check in both
then post result here

Comment: I have finally figured out the problem, it was a bug in my code! There was no default value for ResourceManager localeChain on the first initialization of the app. I was not seeing this problem on my testing devices as the app had saved the localechain value in the device local storage. Every time i do a new development build and install on my devices, it would read the saved localechain on the first initialization. Thank you Patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured out the problem, it was a bug in my code! There was no default value for ResourceManager localeChain on the first initialization of the app. I was not seeing this problem on my testing devices as the app had saved the localechain value in the device local storage. Every time i do a new development build and install on my devices, it would read the saved localechain on the first initialization. Thank you Patel

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you must embedded font in you app. its a common scenario say when your system have XYZ font, so your app in your system give proper output, so there have different case say someone have a font so not got an issue but someone may be not installed font in his system at that time what our application do????? simple nothing. so i have solution for this question is to embedded a font in your app. 
several way to embedded font in your app

first way(in css)

`@font-face { 
    src: url("location"); 
    fontFamily: alias; 
    [fontStyle: normal | italic | oblique] ; 
    [fontWeight: normal | bold | heavy] ; 
    [embedAsCFF:true | false] ; 
    [advancedAntiAliasing: true | false]; 
}
 .customStyle {
            fontFamily: myFontFamily;
            fontSize: 24;
            skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin");
        }`

second way(in Main app)

`<fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";`

```
    @font-face { 
        src: url("../assets/MyriadWebPro.ttf"); 
        fontFamily: myFontFamily; 
        embedAsCFF: false; 
    }       
    .customStyle {
        fontFamily: myFontFamily;
        fontSize: 24;
        skinClass: ClassReference("spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin");
    }   
</fx:Style>
```

for more help on embedding a font in your app go to
http://divillysausages.com/blog/as3_font_embedding_masterclass

may this will help you

Regards
JK Patel

Comment: Thank you Patel and Adrian, I will try this. I have tested the app on the same device for both development and release builds. The app works perfectly fine with development builds, but not with release builds.